# Scrolling in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm seeing something weird in GNU screen.  When I use screen on my own Ubuntu 10.04 box, as I enter a bunch of lines in the shell, I can see my GNOME-terminal window gathering my scrollback, and I can then scroll back up in GNOME-terminal with e.g. mouse wheel, Shift-PgUp, etc.

But on my friend's machine with the same Ubuntu 10.04 installed, screen for some reason doesn't do this.  It never "leaves behind" more than the current screen in GNOME-terminal, so the scrollbar never changes size, and trying to scroll with the mouse wheel just gets interpreted as the Up key, causing the shell to go to the previous line.

We pored over our `.screenrc` and `.inputrc`, but couldn't find what was causing this.  It doesn't seem to matter anyway since if I create an entirely new user on my own box, and an entirely new user on his box, both of which have no custom `.inputrc`/`.screenrc`, we still see this discrepancy.  It's all version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06.  Any help?

Comment: Have you tried [disabling the alternate screen feature](http://superuser.com/questions/126606/how-to-get-mac-os-x-terminal-app-and-screen-vim-scrolling-to-play-nice) anyway? If this changes one of these to the other's behavior, at least you know what setting is responsible, and can then figure out where it's set. You could also check the `$TERM` environment variable - I don't know how Gnome Terminal works, maybe it's different for your systems?

Comment: @DanielBeck `$TERM` was the answer.  I had to change it from xterm to xterm-256color.  If you change your comment to an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [setting](https://superuser.com/questions/126606/how-to-get-mac-os-x-terminal-app-and-screen-vim-scrolling-to-play-nice) that controls whether screen and other applications allow scroll back through the terminal itself depends on your `$TERM`. Make sure both machines have the same value.